If a group G has a cyclic Sylow p-group do the elements of order p "spread out evenly" over the conjugacy classes of elements of order p?
I have been working in some character theory recently and most specifically I have been using this formula,
$$\operatorname{dim}C_V(g)=\frac{1}{o(g)}\sum_{i=1}^{o(g)}\chi(g^i)$$
Where we are working in some irreducible representation of a group G and chi is its corresponding character. In the semidirect product between G and the vector space of corresponding dimension the centralizer of an element can be described this way. (I hope this makes sense).
In this paper I have been reading, they imply that the dimension found above of any prime order element where the sylow p-subgroups are cyclic will be the same. Not the same between different primes, but all elements of order p will share the same dimension.
From my observations this seems to be because the the elements of prime power order distribute evenly over the conjugacy classes of the group. By this I mean that if there are cyclic 41 sylow subgroups and 5 conjugacy classes of elements of order 41 that from each cyclic subgroup 8 elements go to each of the conjugacy classes. The paper kind of just uses this without citation, which is fine, but I was hoping to make a similar argument and need this distribution to always be true.
Is there any citation where I could find the reasoning behind this? Or are there any proofs as to why this is the case?

In a cyclic group of prime order, every non-trivial element is a power of every other one. Since $C_V(g)\leq C_V(g^i)$ for any $i\in \mathbb Z$ (but in general we need not have equality), we obtain $C_V(g)\leq C_V(g^i)\leq C_V(g)$, so they are all equal (except if $g^i=1$).

Upon reflection with my groupmates we understand why this formula works for all elements of order p. This is because under this representation they correspond to matrices and something in the centralizer of that matrix just means that it contains eigenvalue of 1. Since the sylow p-group is cyclic all elements of order p are conjugate to each other which means all their matrices under this representation are conjugate to each other. Therefore the eigenvalues are retained over all matrices corresponding to elements of order p. So if one element has no e-val of 1, none of them can.

Please use MathJax/TeX syntax to include mathematics in posts, rather than images.

All elements of order $p$ are not conjugate to one another in a group with a cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup. For example, the dihedral group of order $10$ and $p=5$. Or, as a more trivial example, the cyclic group of order $p$.

Okay, I think I can explain better what I mean. So $$C_V(g)=C_V(g^i)$$ for any i such that $$g^i \neq 1$$. So we can say that this centralizer is consistent over each p-group. Furthermore since every sylow p-group is conjugate we can push this equality through every element of order p. If $$C_V(g)=2$$ then $$C_V(g^i)=2$$ and since every Sylow p-group is conjugate there is some element $$ag^ia^{-1} = k$$ where $$o(k)=p$$. Then we use the conjugacy argument from before to say that $$C_V(k)=2$$ as well.

It was the first part that I was explaining, as I assumed that was what you were stuck on. In general the centralizer of $g^i$ merely contains that of $g$. But a cyclic group of prime order has the property that every non-trivial element is a power of every other one, and so you obtain equality. if $g$ has order $4$ then $C_V(g)<C_V(g^2)$ is possible (and quite likely).
